# Save the .css file generated by less.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I know that it is not recommended to use less.js to compile the .css on a production website, however I had to do that for a reason instead of using third party compilers (which I find more than useful for general purpose compiling). The question is *how do I reach the css styles the less.js compiler generated* (to e.g. save them in a different file)? Below is how I had to compile my less files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="assets/less/styles.less" />

<script>
  var less = {
    modifyVars: {
      '@brand-primary': 'yellow'
    }
  };
</script>

<script src="less.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not save the generated .css file via browser. You have to do this on the server side via PHP or Node.js:

```
import fs   from 'fs';
import less from 'less';

less.render('.class { width: (1 + 1) }', (error, output) => {
  fs.writeFile('/path/to/file.css', output)
});
```